# How to pass a list of sources to 'from_py_func' callback in bokeh python?

Tags: python, bokeh

In [CustomJS with a Python function example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#customjs-with-a-python-function) the callback is taking data from the variable 'source'. I want to pass 'source' also, but my 'source' is actually a list made up of column data sources.

I have tried:
def callback(source, window=None):
    for i in range(source):
        data = source[i].data

I have tried combining my sources into one ultimate source, but I get errors because the column lengths are not the same (the reason I made a list of column data sources in the first place).

The only success I have seen is:
def callback(source=source[0], window=None):

but this only changes one of my data sets.

Here is my full code currently, which only works on the first source:

```
def SMAcallback(source=source[0], window=None):

    data = source.data
    f = cb_obj.value
    x, y = data['x'], data['y']
    topx, midx, botx, = data['topx'], data['midx'], data['botx']
    topy, midy, boty, = data['topy'], data['midy'], data['boty']

    avg = sum(y) * 1.0 / len(y)
    variance = map(lambda t: (t - avg) ** 2, y)
    varAvg = sum(variance) * 1.0 / len(variance)
    std_dev = window.Math.sqrt(varAvg)

    y_avg = []
    x_day_list = []
    for d in range(0, f - 1):
        y_avg.append("Nan")
        x_day_list.append("NaN")
    for d in range(f, len(y)):
        tot = sum(y[d - f:d])
        avg = tot / f
        y_avg.append(avg)
        x_day_list.append(x[d])

    top_Band = []
    bot_Band = []
    mid_Band = []

    curSD = std_dev
    curSMA = y_avg

    for i in range(len(y)):
        top_Band.append(curSMA[i] + (curSD * 2))
        bot_Band.append(curSMA[i] - (curSD * 2))
        mid_Band.append(curSMA[i])

    for i in range(len(y)):
        topy[i] = top_Band[i]
        midy[i] = mid_Band[i]
        boty[i] = bot_Band[i]

        topx[i] = x_day_list[i]
        midx[i] = x_day_list[i]
        botx[i] = x_day_list[i]
    source.change.emit()

SMAwindow_slider = Slider(start=1, end=100, value=20, step=1,
                          title="SMA Window(days)", callback=CustomJS.from_py_func(SMAcallback))
```

I am trying to make a slider that changes the days in which we are calculating the simple moving average. I am thinking I could possibly make a slider for each seperate source, but it would not look good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could come up with, was converting all of the python code to javascript. This way I could pass a dict that included the "source" variable. Then I could call each source in the javascript - source0, source1, source2, etc.

I knew this would be possible, but I am not as familiar with javascript as python.